MySQL Workbench Visual Explain won't work
I'm beginning my journey to learn SQL.
For some reason when I run a query go to the Execution Plan and try to switch to Visual Explain it won't work and stay on the Tabular Explain.
I've downloaded the most recent version of the MySQL Workbench (Currently 8.0 CE)
Is there a quick fix for this situation or something else needed to be configured or installed?
After Clicking Visual Explain
I've looked for other queries on this website but it all seemed like they were outdated and irrelevant for my current situation tried to find another way to access the Visual Explain without much luck

If you're question is about MySQL and MySQL Workbench, then it cannot possibly be about Microsoft SQL Server. Please read tag descriptions before adding them.

It seems to be related to the version of MySQL you are using. using 5.7, I do see for example this, but when using 9.0, I do not see the visual explain plan.

Also related to MySQL bug
